how to customise the SNS email sent when an object is uploaded into s3 bucket to the user
I am unable to customise the message which is sent to user when an object is uploaded instead its sending whole s3 event in the mail.
I tried in push message option but it will inly send that message only once but i need this message every time an object is uploaded.

This doesn't happen without something configured on your side.  Do you have a Lambda or other event destination configured for the S3 event?
